# Magento singleton setSubscriptionPlan

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magic-getter

I am new to Magento. I am facing problem while using Customweb subscription extension. so there is an error in file causing by this extension. what I want to know is, what is this code doing?

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
...
$subscriptionPlan = Mage::getModel('customweb_subscription/cartPlan')->loadByIndex($index);
...
$quote->setSubscriptionPlan($subscriptionPlan)->collectTotals()->save();
```

I am trying to search "setSubscriptionPlan" in every files in the Customweb Subscription folder, but can't find this method defined. What exactly this method do, and where can I find this method in a file?

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*: add complete code.

```
class Customweb_Subscription_IndexController extends Customweb_Subscription_Controller_Abstract {

    /**
     * Apply subscription plan to cart
     */
    public function applyPlanAction(){
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

        /**
         * No reason continue with empty shopping cart
         */
        if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $index = $this->getRequest()->getParam('subscription_plan');
        if ($index != '') {
            $subscriptionPlan = Mage::getModel('customweb_subscription/cartPlan')->loadByIndex($index);
        }
        else {
            $subscriptionPlan = null;
        }

        $oldSubscriptionPlan = $quote->getSubscriptionPlan();

        if ($subscriptionPlan == null && $oldSubscriptionPlan == null) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        try {
            $quote->setSubscriptionPlan($subscriptionPlan)->collectTotals()->save();

            if ($subscriptionPlan != null) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess(
                        $this->__('You subscribed to the plan <em>%s</em>.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($subscriptionPlan->getDescription())));
            }
            else {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The subscription plan was removed.'));
            }
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Cannot apply the subscription plan.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }

        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
```

Gets the quote from the current user

```
$subscriptionPlan = Mage::getModel('customweb_subscription/cartPlan')->loadByIndex($index);
```

I have no clue what index is, but it loads some kind of cartPlan (whatever this is), based on an index.

```
$quote->setSubscriptionPlan($subscriptionPlan)->collectTotals()->save();
```

I would say, this applies the loaded plan on the quote, then it `collectTotals` which means it calculate all prices, taxes, shipping, etc. and saves the quote

Comment: thank you for the answer. i got the following error `Recoverable Error: Object of class Customweb_Subscription_Model_CartPlan could not be converted to string`. therefor I want to know what `setSubscriptionPlan`. I tried to pass serialized data to `setSubscriptionPlan` but it throw error as well, different error though.

Comment: setSubscriptionplan is a standard setter in Magento check `\Varien_Object::__call` for more infos. Nowhere in your code is a conversion to string, so either you post your complete code or we can't help

Comment: There can be a conversion to string. In fact, it's very likely. \Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareTableValueForSave only has provisions for numeric types. Since we know it goes via the magic setter and is passed an object, it should be marked serializable or implemented in the resource model to handle the link.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I updated the question with complete code. thanks